# Execute multiple `terraform apply` in a bash `for loop` and state management

Tags: azure, terraform, databricks

I'm new to terraform and trying to create Databricks jobs (hosted on azure) with it, so as you can see in the screenshot below (Project structure), I have created a terraform folder containing terraform code needed to provision those jobs/pipelines/copy the files to workspace etc. I'm running these apply commands with a parameter that changes every time, that parameter is the name of the folder inside the `jobs` folder. The apply command is being run inside a for loop as shown below:

```bash
for job_file_dir_path in ../databricks/jobs/* ; do
    terraform apply -var artifactory_user=$ARTIFACTORY_USER \
                  -var artifactory_api_key=$ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY \
                  -var project_name=project \
                  -var job_file_dir_path=$job_file_dir_path
done
```

Project structure screenshot:

[image]

The thing is for each iteration in the loop, as the provisioned jobs/pipelines depends on the parameter `job_file_dir_path`, terraform will assume that the previously provisioned resource in the previous jobs needs to be destroyed, and only the ones from the current iteration will be created, so by the end of the loop only the resource with the latest value of `job_file_dir_path` will be provisioned.

I understand that this might be a very typical beginner problem and there might be a better way on how to do this, therefore I kindly ask for your support if anyone has an idea on how to handle this.

An example file that contains resources provisioning is `workspace_file.tf` which copies local files to a Databricks workspace. I've copied its content below

```
# Iterate over each python file in <job_file_dir_path>
# Each python file represents a task
resource "databricks_workspace_file" "workspace_file" {
  for_each = fileset(var.job_file_dir_path, "*.py")
  source = "${var.job_file_dir_path}/${each.value}"
  path = "/Shared/job_files/${var.project_name}/${local.job_name}/${each.value}"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would it be possible to add the terraform code to the question? Because this way, with only a screenshot, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Yes apologies, the main 3 files that contains resource are `jobs.tf`, `dlt.tf` and `workspace_file.tf`, they're all written the same way (using the parameter `job_file_dir_path` and for simplicity I've added the code for `workspace_file.tf` to the thread above. Thanks!

Comment: So the `databricks_workspace_file` resource does not create what you need?

Comment: I doubt it's possible of what you are trying to achieve here. `terraform apply` will always look for a state file which would be created by `terraform init`. 

So in your shell script you have to embed `terraform init -backend-config` pointing to some remote state file & then run `apply/plan/destroy` referring to the same state file. 

To make this easy there is a tool called [terragrunt](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/) which makes life easy

Comment: @MarkoE It does, however in the next each iteration it will destroy the previously created resources and create new ones, and so on for each iteration until keeping only the resources created with the value of the `job_file_dir_path` from the last iteration.

Comment: @harshavmb Thanks for the tool's link. Do you suggest then doing a `terraform init` for each iteration in the for loop, with a parameterised back-end to which the state file is corresponding to the specific iteration?

Answer (score 0):

When you run `terraform init`, Terraform initializes the current working directory based on the backend configuration specified in your root module, and "remembers" that information for use in subsequent commands like `terraform apply`.

That means that the state storage location to use is effectively locked in by running `terraform init`, and cannot vary between other commands.

If your goal is to have multiple separate state snapshots for your configuration -- one per directory in your `for` loop, I suppose -- then there are two main options to choose from.

## Multiple Workspaces

Terraform CLI has a concept called [workspaces](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state/workspaces) which allow you to store multiple separate named state snapshots in the same backend, for the same configuration. When you create a new workspace, this establishes a new separate storage location in your chosen backend, named after the workspace you've created.

The selected workspace is another piece of information that persists between commands, but this one can be modified separately from `terraform init` using [`terraform workspace select`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/workspace/select). You can also override the persistent workspace selection by setting the `TF_WORKSPACE` environment variable, which I think is probably a better fit here because you want to control the workspace selection on a per-command basis.

So assuming you've already created a workspace for each of your directories, you could modify your script like this:

```
for job_file_dir_path in ../databricks/jobs/* ; do
    workspace_name=$(basename "$job_file_dir_path")
    TF_WORKSPACE="$workspace_name" terraform apply -var artifactory_user="$ARTIFACTORY_USER" \
                  -var artifactory_api_key="$ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY" \
                  -var project_name=project \
                  -var job_file_dir_path="$job_file_dir_path"
done
```

---

## Re-initializing the Backend

If you need more segregation between your state snapshots than just using a different storage location in a single backend -- for example, if you want to store the state for each directory in an entirely separate storage bucket, rather than just a different path in the same bucket -- then an alternative is to totally re-initialize the working directory on each iteration.

You can use the `-reconfigure` option to `terraform init` to tell Terraform to ignore whatever backend configuration was previously initialized, as opposed to trying to migrate the state from one storage location to another.

```
for job_file_dir_path in ../databricks/jobs/* ; do
    terraform init -reconfigure -backend-config="..."
    terraform apply -var artifactory_user="$ARTIFACTORY_USER" \
                  -var artifactory_api_key="$ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY" \
                  -var project_name=project \
                  -var job_file_dir_path="$job_file_dir_path"
done
```

To ensure that each iteration does indeed use a distinct storage location, you'll need to include at least one `-backend-config` option to `terraform init` to override one of the arguments in the backend configuration to vary between iterations. I've used `...` as a placeholder here just because I don't know what might make sense for the backend you've chosen and for the architecture of your system.

`terraform init` will, by default, also try to make your installed dependencies consistent each time, which might have a performance cost. If you find that delay bothersome, you could potentially use the `-get=false` and `-get-plugins=false` options to `terraform init` to disable those steps, but you'll need to make sure you've previously run `terraform init` at least once without those options to get the needed dependencies installed in the local cache directory.

---

These two options both achieve essentially the same thing -- reconfiguring where Terraform stores the state dynamically based on information that varies between iterations of the `for` loop -- but the first one does it using a built-in feature of your selected backend while the second essentially does it *in spite of* your selected backend, by overriding parts of its configuration dynamically on each iteration.

The approach with Workspaces has the slight advantage that it avoids modifying any persistent working directory state between iterations, and thus avoids adding an extra command to each iteration. However, aside from that the two approaches are essentially equivalent, and reconfiguring the backend each time gives some more flexibility in exactly what will vary from one iteration from the next; any part of the backend configuration can vary, in principle.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I've indeed opted for the second approach and now using a different snapshot of state for each iteration (corresponding to a databricks job), each stored a separate blob inside the same Blob storage container, and it's working as expected now.